# Min function not working properly in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a macro right now and it's producing weird results. The part that is specifically not working is a Min function.

```
a1RowTemp1 = a1Row
For i = 0 To diff1
intercept = Application.WorksheetFunction.intercept(a(),c())
LinReg1 = (slope * Cells(a1RowTemp1, 1)) + intercept 
difference1 = Worksheets("GF9").Cells(a1RowTemp1, 2) - LinReg1              
e(i) = difference1
a1RowTemp1 = a1RowTemp1 + 1
Next i

a2RowTemp2 = a2Row

For i = 0 To diff2
intercept2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.intercept(b(), d())
LinReg2 = (slope2 * Cells(a2RowTemp2, 1)) +   intercept2
difference2 = Worksheets("GF9").Cells(a2RowTemp2, 2) - LinReg2
f(i) = difference2  
a2RowTemp2 = a2RowTemp2 + 1
Next i


Worksheets("Chart").Cells(currentRow, 12) = Application.Max(e())
Worksheets("Chart").Cells(currentRow, 13) = Application.Min(e())
Worksheets("Chart").Cells(currentRow, 25) = Application.Max(f())
Worksheets("Chart").Cells(currentRow, 26) = Application.Min(f())
```

In the bottom of the code it stores the difference1 and difference2 values in arrays e() and f(). When I use the functions max/min the macro only outputs the correct values for the max functions. I suspect this has something to do with my incorrectly using the arrays.

Comment: @QHarr I had that at first and then changed it to what I have now. I found that it made no difference.

Comment: Without the () for e

Comment: Yes, I removed the (), and I am still getting the wrong results. When I first use e() to find the max, the numbers in e() are correct; however, when I use it again to find the min, the numbers in e() are incorrect.

Comment: you may need to supply some data and expected output. The syntax I have show below is fine for finding min of 1d array.

Comment: Have you inspected the contents of e?

Comment: The contents of e are correct before I use the max function. The problem is after the max function e seems to be empty and that's why the min function is giving me wrong values.

Comment: So e is being filled incorrectly. Step through I guess and work out why. I can't see from the above how that can be the case with the flow shown. My guess would be a long the lines of @jeeped's statement.

Answer (score 1):

If e is one dimensional array you should be able to write

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(e)
```

Example:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim e()
    e = Array(3, 4, 2, 5)
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(e)
End Sub
```

If you are still getting the wrong values you need to step though with <kbd>F8</kbd> and check the values being assigned to `e` in the loop are the expected ones.

Comment: I suspect that *e* and *f* have more elements than *diff1* and *diff2*. That would explain the fact that max works but min is probably returning an instantiated but unassigned value of zero. ReDim e(diff1) before the loop or ReDim Preserve(i-1) after the loop could correct this.

Comment: @jeeped That sounds logical. You should post as an answer . Gets my vote :-)

Comment: Hello, Jeeped, I actually did have ReDim e(diff1) and ReDim f(diff2) earlier in the macro.

Comment: @Jeeped Connection is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You've omitted the declaration and dimensioning of the *e* and *f* array. This was an important factor in your problem.

When you declared your *e* and *f* as long or double arrays, they were instantiated with zero values.

```
Dim v() As Double, i As Long
ReDim v(5)    '<~~ all zero values
For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v) - 1   '<~~fill all but the last one
    v(i) = i + 10
Next i
Debug.Print Application.Min(v)  'zero as v(5) is zero
```

If you want to ignore array elements that you have not assigned values to, declare the arrays as a variant type.

```
Dim v() As Variant, i As Long
ReDim v(5)    '<~~ all empty values
For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v) - 1   '<~~fill all but the last one
    v(i) = i + 10
Next i
Debug.Print Application.Min(v)  '10 as v(5) is empty and not considered in Min
```

An unassigned variant array element is considered empty and is not used in the Min calculation.

Alternately, use one of two methods to remove unused array elements.

```
'...

'redimension before the loop to the known ubound
redim e(diff1)
For i = 0 To diff1
    intercept = Application.WorksheetFunction.intercept(a(),c())
    LinReg1 = (slope * Cells(a1RowTemp1, 1)) + intercept 
    difference1 = Worksheets("GF9").Cells(a1RowTemp1, 2) - LinReg1              
    e(i) = difference1
    a1RowTemp1 = a1RowTemp1 + 1
Next i

'...

'or redimension after the loop with Preserve
For i = 0 To diff2
    intercept2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.intercept(b(), d())
    LinReg2 = (slope2 * Cells(a2RowTemp2, 1)) +   intercept2
    difference2 = Worksheets("GF9").Cells(a2RowTemp2, 2) - LinReg2
    f(i) = difference2  
    a2RowTemp2 = a2RowTemp2 + 1
Next i
'i exits with a value 1 greater than diff2
redim preserve f(i-1)

'...
```